# Do you need all tiers for monthlies

Tags: guild-wars-2

If your doing a monthly achievement, do you need to complete all 4 tiers of 4 items to unlock the chest at the end or does the quality of the chest just drop when you don't get all tiers to 4?

Comment: I did :) the Wiki wasn't too clear about that specific area. It said there are 4 tiers but it didn't say if you need to complete them all.

Comment: "Monthly is an achievement category earned by completing four special achievement tracks during a single month. Players can complete up to three additional tracks for additional experience." Sounds pretty clear to me.... complete _all_ 4 for monthlies, complete additional ones for more XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For doing the monthly achievments in Guild Wars 2 you need to complete all 4 tiers of 4 out of 7 achievements to unlock the chest. Otherwise there is simply no chest (you receive it after finishing all 4).

You can read more about the monthly achievments on the Guild Wars 2 Official Wiki Page: [Monthly](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Monthly)

The rewards you get from the chest by the way are always the same:

- 50 Silver
- 20 Mystic Coins
- 10 Jugs of Liquid Karma
- 10 Laurels

Comment: To clarify: There are more than 4 options, but you only need to complete 4 of those options. Completing one option requires you to complete all 4 tiers of that option. For example, Monthly Event Participation will reward you with experience and achievement points for 25, 50, 75, and 100 events completed, but you need 100 for it to count towards the monthly chest.

Comment: Further options completed still award ANet points, for those who want to hoard them... :)